# jquery keyup removeClass doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one question.

I am trying to make a `addClass`, `removeClass` button function for after the text `length > 5` or something else.

So the `addClass` working fine in my code but `removeClass` doesn't work. What I am missing here or what I am doing wrong here anyone can help me in this regard ?

I have tried the following code also please click for **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/YqJmad)**:

```
// Keypress for active inactive button
    $(".PGA51c").on('keyup', function() {
      var ID = $(this).attr('data-id');
      var cm = $('#PCm' + ID);
      if (cm.text.length < 5) {
         $('#sev' + ID).addClass('tCo');
         console.log('OK');
      } else {
         $('#sev' + ID).removeClass('tCo');
         console.log('Not OK');
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `text()` instead of `text` in `if` condition.

```
$(".PGA51c").on('keyup', function() {
    var ID = $(this).attr('data-id');        
    var cm = $('#PCm' + ID);
    if (cm.text().length < 5) {
    //-----^^^^^^--------------
        $('#sev' + ID).addClass('tCo');
        console.log('OK');
    } else {
        $('#sev' + ID).removeClass('tCo');
        console.log('Not OK');
    }
});
```

Comment: ahh thank you that is very easy oh my god. Sometimes we really do not see a lot of unforced errors. Thanks again.